# Java 2d Games Key Listener Time Limit

Tags: java, key, 2d

I am trying to make a 2d Dungeon Crawlers style game in Java. I have set it so when the x key is pressed, a knight attacks. The problem I have is that when I press the x key, the knight is set to attack but it keeps on attacking and the knight is able to keep on killing skeletons. I am wondering if there would be an easy way to timeout the key press after 500 ms.

Code

```
public Knight k = new Knight();

private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        k.keyReleased(e);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        k.keyPressed(e);
    }
}

//Code in Knight

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_X)) {
               Attacking = true;
        }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_X)) {
                Attacking = false;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is written to set attack while key is pressed, and you disable attack when key is released.

Instead of this implementation, you can write that attack will start on key press by calling method which will provide attack functionalities and in functionalities method implement all logic where you can explicitly set all conditions.

You can ensure that attack will stop on key release as you already did.